# InMemoryUploadedFile Django File Read in Bytes - str vs utf8

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to read the binary content of a Django type InMemoryUploadedFile. The file type/encoding is a variable, so I don't want to assume UTF8, I simply want to read the binary content, then I want to encode with UTF8. Here's what I've tried:

```
str(file.read()).replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

This looks to work, except the string still has the binary 'b' character. To fix this, I tried:

```
file.read().decode('utf8').replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

This works well for reading .txt files. Any other file types fail to read properly, understandably. How can I read the binary content of type "InMemoryUploadedFile" without specifying an encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the string still has the binary 'b' character" is the wrong approach to think about here (and in general will lead you to just pain down the line, with Python and encodings).

Instead, use [Django's `force_str` helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.force_str) to decode a `bytes` to a text string (instead of using `str` to generate a *representation* of a bytestring as a text string):

```
force_str(file.read()).replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

This of course only works for text that can be decoded; binary content has no inherent encoding (after all, how would you decode e.g. a PNG image as text?).

Comment: Thanks for the assist. How would I read, say, an exe file then? Ultimately the intention here is to pass the data to PowerShell and re-write the content of a exe file.

Comment: An exe file is binary, so you wouldn't want to `str()` it at all. What would PowerShell do with that binary data?

Comment: If you want a base64 string to pass forward, `base64.b64encode()` the bytes.

Comment: Using base64.b64encode(local_filename.read()) does not let me encode as it's not text. That example claims the data is encoded before passed to Powershell. Either the example is wrong, or I'm fundementally misunderstanding something.

Comment: What is `local_filename`? If you're opening it as text, it won't be bytes.

Comment: local_filename (or file in the original post) is: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>

Comment: ... Yes? Now `text` will be the base64 encoding of the binary content from the uploaded file.

Comment: So then text = force_str(base64.b64encode(local_filename.read())) works! Now I just need to figure out if a file is UTF8 encoded or not. Thank you!

Comment: @AKX : Hi, Can you pls check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559004/user-login-in-django